# Is it precise to use `requests` to check if a domain name is registered?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3, http.client

I noticed that requesting an invalid url `requests.get(invalid_url)` throws the following exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 530, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 607, in urlopen
    raise MaxRetryError(self, url, e)
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='sparkandshine.me', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 378, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='sparkandshine.me', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

**Is it precise to determine whether a domain name is registered or not by catching those exceptions?** Here is the source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import http
import urllib3
import requests

url = 'http://example.com'
try :
    r = requests.get(url)
except (http.client.HTTPException, urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError):
    print(url) #this domain name is not registered?
```

Comment: The best way of checking domain availability is whois, I guess, rather than simply trying to resolving that name.

Comment: @CongMa I just got to know there is a python module named [pywhois](https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/pywhois). To install it, `pip install python-whois`.

Comment: No existing module as I know. You'd better use `requests` to search the domain on `godaddy`

Comment: Not very precise, because this exceptions can be raised because of wrong DNS settings or other network problems. They do not precisely mean, that such domain does not registered.

Comment: @LittleQ How about the python module [pywhois](https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/pywhois)?

Comment: It lookup domain on some `whois` server. You can check the source code: https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/pywhois/src. I have no idea if it covers all edge cases. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; it is perfectly fine for a domain to be registered and not have an IP address for the root domain name, let alone have a server run on port 80 of that IP address.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @tripleee, it is not very precise. I find another way to determine if a domain name is registered or not, using the python module [pywhois](https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/pywhois/).

To install it,

```
pip install python-whois
```

Here is an example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import whois

url = 'example.com'
try :
    w = whois.whois(url)
except (whois.parser.PywhoisError):
    print(url)
```

PS: not support for python3.

Comment: There ase multiple Python whois clients, but any one of them should work for the trivial case of checking whether a domain exists or not. The differences will be in handling the chain of responses to find the authoritative registrar and parsing the typically not machine-readable details of a record. It's still not perfect because some TLDs don't support whois, and force you to use their own nonstandard query system, typically a custom web-based job.